# Изменения работают только после очистки кэша в браузере(хостинг)

Tags: хостинг, ispmanager

Есть сайт на хостинге, если поменять стили(CSS) ну или прописать скрипты-JS,
то все эти изменения не будут работать пока вручную не очистить кэш в браузере.

В браузере показывается версия сайта до всех этих манипуляций,
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀    ⠀⠀⠀⠀    **помогает очистка кэша в браузере за все время.**

Но ладно я знаю, а если другие пользователи об этом не знают, то у них будет показываться версия сайта до всех этих манипуляций.
**Как пофиксить этот баг?**

P.S.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀    ⠀⠀⠀⠀   ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀    ⠀⠀⠀⠀
Например:
допустим я изменю свой старый цвет(белый) меню на новый(красный),
то красный цвет меню не будет видно пока пользователь вручную не очистить кэш браузера.
Получается, что я зря менял цвет меню? Раз его не видят другие пользователи?

Comment: Отправлять с сервера HTTP-заголовок Cache-Control, который будет ограничивать длительность кэширования или полностью запрещать его

Comment: Или переименовывать файлы после каждого их изменения

Comment: И это не баг, а фича. Управление кэшированием во всех подробностях расписано в спецификации HTTP

Comment: Где прописывать этот  Cache-Control? И что писать конкретно?

Comment: В том месте сайта, которое занимается формированием заголовков HTTP-ответа. Что писать конкретно — изучите в какой-нибудь документации (например на MDN)

Comment: Я не могу понять, где это место. Нужно это писать в head в html? Не могли бы вы показать пример кода.

Comment: А что за вариант про переименования файлов?